# Testing CloudFormation for security smells

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I like an API-based service to validate AWS CloudFormation templates for potential security problems. Like 0.0.0.0/0 openings on port 22 or unencrypted s3 buckets, etc. 
I've found the OSS 'cfn_nag' and figure about to build wrap an RESTful API around it.

But are there any other solition out there that solves my needs?

Comment: Not aware of a service that takes CloudFormation templates and does this security analysis, but AWS has runtime solutions such as Trusted Advisor and AWS Config Rules.

Comment: I'm looking into OSS cfn_nag and CloudSpolit now.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm not aware of any service or tool, that is capable of parsing a CloudFormation JSON and detect security smells.

However if you provision the resources using CloudFormation, then there are many tools and services which can analyse the infrastructure for Security smells and beyond. You can use [AWS inspector](https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/), [AWS trusted advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/) or find a [AWS security partner solution](https://aws.amazon.com/security/partner-solutions/) suiting your needs.